# Disable multiline in prompt dialog text field and choose keyboard layout

Tags: dialog, keyboard, textfield, prompt, nativescript

Disable multiline in prompt dialog text field and choose keyboard layout Disable multiline in prompt dialog text field and choose keyboard layout Disable multiline in prompt dialog text field and choose keyboard layout Disable multiline in prompt dialog text field and choose keyboard layout

Answer (score 1):

This feature for {N} **prompt** dialog is not currently supported but you have some options for your application. There are some posibilities .. one of them involves creating a custom prompt-page with **showModal()**

The idea is that you can create your custom prompt page with all the setting as required and then show it as a modal view and tehn use **closeModal()** to close it.
More about modal pages you can get from the {N} documentation here : 
https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/page/Page.html

Here you can find a demo for showing and closing modal view:
https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/tree/master/apps/modal-views-demo